# Adding a package to spring boot (java)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, slack-api

Im trying to add 'bolt' from slack to my application but im not sure how.
The documentation says just to add this to the build.gradle but i dont have this file anywhere in the project

```
implementation("com.slack.api:bolt:1.3.0")
```

Comment: is there any `pom.xml` file exists?

Comment: Yes there is - I have tried this <groupId>com.slack.api:bolt:1.3.0</groupId> but it doesnt do anything

Comment: that's because that's not how it works. https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html

Answer (score 3):

Add this inside `pom.xml` under `<dependencies>` tag:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.slack.api/bolt -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.slack.api</groupId>
    <artifactId>bolt</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Are these packages pre-bundled or do they somehow get installed at runtime?